# Saving a state within a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a ruby on rails web application that uses a javascript function to update a component on a page.

All I want to do is have the web site 'remember' the value for when the user reloads the page and/or returns after re-loading.

The javascript is very simple.  All I want to do is something like this...

```
$('#my_field').change(function() {
  $('#result').html = 'a new value'
});
```

only have the 'result' component retain 'a new value' after the user reloads the page.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using **HTML5 local storage** like so:

This will store a value in local storage
localStorage.setItem('value','a new value');

You can now get that value like so:
var oldValue = localStorage.getItem('value');

This will work much like cookies, but it is all done client side!

In your example you can use this:

```
$('#my_field').change(function() {
  localStorage.setItem('value',$('#result').val());
});
```

When you go the page again after refresh you can get the value:

```
var oldValue = localStorage.getItem('value');
```

Answer (score 1):

The html() method sets or returns the content (innerHTML) of the selected elements.

```
$('#my_field').change(function() {
  $('#result').html('a new value');
});
```